# The apk must be signed with the same certificates even if old one is not correct

Tags: android, certificate, publish

Hy,
yesterday, I publish an app on play store. I have done a big mistake, I signed the app with debug.keystore so the map is not shown when the app is published.

to solve this, I resign the app with a new keystore and generate a new map key (with new sh1).
but the problem that i can't now publish the new apk, they said (The apk must be signed with the same certificates).

what I can do now ?

Comment: I think your best option is to unpublish your app, rebuild it with a new package name and upload it as a brand new app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same certificate when you update your apk or Google Play won't recognize it as the same app.

From Google documentation

> Application upgrade – As you release updates to your application, you must continue to sign the updates with the same certificate or set of certificates, if you want users to be able to upgrade seamlessly to the new version. When the system is installing an update to an application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly, including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows the update. If you sign the new version without using matching certificates, you must also assign a different package name to the application — in this case, the user installs the new version as a completely new application.

Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Similar info also here in Android developer blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

> Just as important as the manifest package name is the certificate that application is signed with. The signing certificate represents the author of the application. If you change the certificate an application is signed with, it is now a different application because it comes from a different author. This different application can’t be uploaded to Market as an update to the original application, nor can it be installed onto a device as an update.
>
> [...]
>
> **In conclusion: There are some parts of your application that can not change. Please be careful.**

So I'm afraid you can't do much in this case.

Comment: thx a lot Szymon, it's seems that the only thing that I can do is to delete the old application and publish it as another application :(

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson. The certificate has to be valid. But Google Play requires the certificate to expire after 22 October 2033 so I guess that's not a real problem. Read the site from the first link, it has all the details.

Comment: This is all non sense, there are several reasons you'd need to reissue new signing certificate like if it gets compromised, stolen or abuse by developers etc.. Apple does not care if you change certs for appstore, they even force you as certificate expiration is shorter. For push service it is one year only. So there must be a way to do it. Verifying that new cert is from same developer cannot be that difficult to do.

Comment: Being able to reissue certificates and invalidate old  due to possible key compromise is a fundamental feature in cryptography.

Comment: @Stan Even if it's all nonsense, it's Google's nonsense.